# Display a list of images in a gridview from SQL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sql-server-2012

Using VS2013 (asp.net, VB) and SQL Server 2012.

I have a table in my database that consists of columns `ID`, `Name` and `ProfilePic`. `ProfilePic` has a type of `image`.

I want to display a list of ALL of the images in a gridview. Looking at google I can only find examples where someone is selecting an image based on an `ID` which is not what I want.

Here is my `imageHandler.ashx`:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="profilePICHandler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class profilePICHandler : Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim con As New SqlConnection()
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("nefsaConnectionString").ConnectionString

    ' Create SQL Command  

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from ProfilePics"
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    Dim dReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dReader.Read()
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(DirectCast(dReader("profilepic"), Byte()))
    dReader.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

On my aspx page I have this

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridSelectAPic" runat="server" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image runat="server" 
                     ImageUrl='<%# "ProfilePICHandler.ashx"%>' 
                     ID="profilePIC" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And on the code behind I have this

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

Using conn
        Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from ProfilePics", conn)
        ad.Fill(dt)
End Using

gridSelectAPic.DataSource = dt
gridSelectAPic.DataBind()
```

I am at a bit of a loss how to proceed so any help greatly appreciated

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Its because your handler is implemented wrong. You will need a *querystring* to tell the handler which image you have to retrieve.

You can use asp:ImageField for brevity and readability. Markup

```
<asp:ImageField HeaderText="Image" 
    DataImageUrlField="EmployeeID" 
    DataImageUrlFormatString="ProfilePICHandler.ashx?id={0}" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" 
                ImageUrl='<%# Eval("EmployeeID", "ProfilePICHandler.ashx?id={0}")%>' 
                ID="profilePIC" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now fetch from querystring from the generic handler like this

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim con As New SqlConnection()
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("nefsaConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("select profilepic from ProfilePics where EmployeeID=", context.Request.QueryString("id"))
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    Dim dReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dReader.Read()
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(DirectCast(dReader("profilepic"), Byte()))
    dReader.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Please note that

1. I have given the name EmployeeID for your PK in DB
2. Your handler name is Pascalcased on Eval and CamelCased at its implementation. Is it a typo?
3. Haven't parameterized the query for brevity.